# Принцип организации маршрутов (роутов) в ASP MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет, есть такой вот роут

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.Add("", new Route("{action}/{controller}", new MvcRouteHandler()));
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
        }
```

в первом добавлении идет `{action}/{controller}`, а во втором наоборот `{controller}/{action}` вопрос в том, что при отправке запроса такого типа `http://localhost:3373/home/index?Name=Vasya&Message=Gleb` выдается ошибка, так как почему-то приложение использует роут №1, добавление во второй роутер слова Default дела не меняет, зато если удалить первый роут, тогда все работает отлично. Почему так и по по какому принципу он решает какой роут будет дефолтным  если не указываются имена роутов ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Маршруты обрабатываются строго в порядке их добавления. Как только будет найден подходящий маршрут, он используется и дальнейший поиск подходящего маршрута не выполняется.

Адрес `http://localhost:3373/home/index` содержит две секции, поэтому подходит под первый шаблон.

Вы пишете:

> добавление во второй роутер слова Default дела не меняет

Вы видимо вот об этой строчке:

```
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
```

Здесь слово `defaults` не означает что этот маршрут надо использовать как дефолтный, оно указывает какие значения подставить в переменные в шаблоне маршрута, если они вдруг пусты. То есть если вы используете только второй маршрут, то адрес

- `/` будет интерпретироваться как `/Home/Index`
- `/Home` тоже будет интерпретироваться как `/Home/Index`

То есть, если в маршруте нет какой-то секции, будет использовано указанное вами дефолтное значение для этой секции.

В вашем случае адрес `home/index` подходит уже под первый ваш маршрут, поэтому до анализа второго маршрута дело даже не доходит.